# Why is my Angular ng-view not displaying anything in bluemix?

Tags: angularjs, ibm-cloud

please help me... I am a new to angular.js and working on a simple application with an ng-view.

The idea is now to run a ng-view in an application that is deployed on bluemix.
The code works fine in plunker. 
If I run and open the app via common Edit Code in DevOps service, the ng-view does not display the views.

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-$route-service-production</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap
    /3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0
    /jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).
    append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + 
    '" />'));
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#/CustomerList"> List Customers </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/CustomerForm"> Add/Edit Customer </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is my script.js:

```
var customerApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
customerApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/CustomerForm',{
            templateUrl: 'customer-form.html',
            controller: "customerCtrl"
        }).
        when('/CustomerList',{
            templateUrl: 'customer-list.html',
            controller: "customerLstCtrl"
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'customer-form'             
        });
    }]);

customerApp.controller('customerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.heading = 'Add / Edit Customer';

}]);

customerApp.controller('customerLstCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.heading = 'Customer List';

}]);
```

And the two views are customer-list.html:

```
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>
```

and the customer-form.html:

```
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>

<div>
    <form>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name" /></br>
        <lablel>Email</lablel>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.email"/></br>
        <label>Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.phone"/></br>
        <label>Address</label>
        <label>Street</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.street" /></br>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.city"/></br>
        <label>State</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.state"/></br>
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="customer.zip"/></br>
    </form>

    </p>{{customer}}</p>
</div>
```

The structure of my app is

```
 - public
 - - js
 - - - app.js
 - - - lib
 - - - - angular-route.min.js
 - - - - angular.min.js
 - - stylesheet
 - - - style.css
 - - customer-form.html
 - - customer-list.html
 - - index.html
```

I coded a sample app, but the ng-view did not work. So tried this app. It was was with CDN angular in plunker and works fine in plunker.

I tried it with CDN-angular in my App but ng-view did not display. Then I changed the source of the angular.min.js w.r.t. the structure of my app, no succes.

Does anybody know why my views are not shown properly here?

Hi this is my app.js:

```
/*eslint-env node*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------   
----
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
----

// This application uses express as its web server
// for more info, see: http://expressjs.com
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
// print a message when the server starts listening
console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

Comment: ho is configured your node server on bluemix ?

Comment: Hi DMCISSOKHO, I added the server configs, got any idea?

Comment: Angular installation is needed on the server too, for routing i think. Is that right? Because my package.json does not have a angular or an angular-route dependency so far

Comment: Yes try to follow this article https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/08/20/simple-angular-node-application/

Comment: Hi thanks, I will do that, also I got one ng-view app running finally, the article helped.Germany says Hi and thx :)))

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think for routing with the ngRoute Service angular needs 2 be installed on the server as well, but we dont have to install it on the server if we use routing with the 3rd hand ui-routing service. This was my first stack overflow question, thank u so much!!!

Comment: Glad you suceed, you can post your answer here to help those who need it